# Transparent Fac showing black in Render

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, transparency

I run randomly mid in my work to a problem, where i don't know the cause of. In the Viewpoint shading it works like it should: If the Fac is on 1(with Transparent BSDF) it is hidden, but after a while, it randomly stoppen "working"(And i really didn't touch anything else except keyframing the Fac to make my animations. This problem somehow occours only on this Stick[Cylinder]. On Text, it hides fully like it should.) and showing in Render a Black Fade, but the Animation after works fine. Also this blacking on the sticks only appear in the Box, outer it is Transparent how you see it in the pictures below. Still the Text ain't blacking in the box(Didn't include the Text in the pictures now):[image: Fac on 0][image: Fac on 1][image: Shading][image: Settings].

Comment: PS: *The Settings and Shading is the same as the Text is, there is no difference, also it worked like it should, till it randomly started doing this.*

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue: The Box was set to: Blend Mode: Alpha Blend, while it should be Opaque, this caused the Stick to black out, Still im wondering why the Text didn't had any problems.